# How is .local folder created with pipx in MSYS2?

Tags: python, windows, msys2, conan, pipx

I'm using MSYS2 on Windows and trying to install conan package manager through pipx.
I'm using pipx since it is creating conan.exe after installation in `.local` folder in:

`C:/Users/MyUser/.local/bin`

I had to reinstall MSYS2 and remove the folders because troubleshooting. And now I can't recreate this folder for some reason.
How can I recreate that folder? Maybe there is some specific command for that?

Tried to clean-up AppData/Local folder but seems no luck in recreating the folder by pipx.

I've tried

`python -m pip install pipx pipx install conan==1.59.0`

But also I can't get `conan --version`:

-bash: conan: command not found

After that, using `pipx install conan again` shows:

`'conan' already seems to be installed. Not modifying existing installation in '/home/MyUser/.local/pipx/venvs/conan`
(actual path is C:/msys64/home/MyUser/.local/pipx/venvs/conan)

**UPDATE**

I can see that my

```
pipx environment
```

Gives me a list of variables beginning with `/home/MyUser/.local`
instead of `C:/Users/MyUser/.local`
How can I change it?

So I want something like this:

```
$ pipx environment
PIPX_HOME=C:/Users/MyUser/.local/pipx
PIPX_BIN_DIR=C:/Users/MyUser/.local/bin
PIPX_SHARED_LIBS=C:/Users/MyUser/.local/pipx/shared
PIPX_LOCAL_VENVS=C:/Users/MyUser/.local/pipx/venvs
PIPX_LOG_DIR=C:/Users/MyUser/.local/pipx/logs
PIPX_TRASH_DIR=C:/Users/MyUser/.local/pipx/.trash
PIPX_VENV_CACHEDIR=C:/Users/MyUser/.local/pipx/.cache

Only PIPX_HOME and PIPX_BIN_DIR can be set by users in the above list.
```